# Wrap text for .bib files in WinEdt

Tags: bibtex, winedt, wrap

I tried using some of the solutions posted on this forum for wrapping text in WinEdt for my .bib files, but what I tried so far does not work.

I tried selecting the "Wrap" option at the bottom of the GUI:

[image]

Also, adding "BIB" to the preferences option and selecting "Wrap Soft Comments":

[image]

These options that I tried still does not wrap the text for my ".bib" files.

Can you tell me what is the solution to wrap the text for the .bib files in WinEdt 10.3 in the Windows 10 environment?  Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to add "BIB" to the modes for soft wrapping as well, but this is just my guess.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, I tried that but I still cannot get the lines to wrap.

Comment: I am doing this from my mind without testing, but when I am not mistaken the value of "Enable Wrapping for Modes" consists of two parts. The ones _left_ of `|` states to `activate` wrapping and the ones _right_ of `|` states to `deactivate` wrapping. So my suggestion would be to move `BIB` before the `|`, i.e. after `ASCII`.

Comment: @Joe, did my comment solve your problem or do you need further assistance?

Comment: @StefanPinnow, yes.  The only caveat that I found is that if you have text inside the `{ }` the line will not break.  That is, if you copy a long line of text within the `{ }`, the line will not break.  Thanks!

Comment: For the (later) wrapping you can use the [bibMacros](http://www.winedt.org/macros/latex/bibMacros.html) AddOn ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow, can you post your solution so that the bounty can go to you?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623450/wrap-text-for-bib-files-in-winedt?noredirect=1#comment1557301_623450) the text fields in the shown screenshot of the `Wrapping` options comprise of *two* parts. The part *left* of the separator `|` which *enables* (soft) wrapping and the part *right* of the separator `|` which *disables* (soft) wrapping.

Said that by adding `BIB` as the last item of the upper text field, which is *right* of `|` you in fact *disabled* wrapping. Simply move it before (left of) `|` and it should work as expected.